# What does the seal on the bottom of this purple clay teapot say

Tags: translation

[image]
Purple clay teapot. I wonder if someone can help me translate it and provide insights into its history.

Comment: image quality is too low, please show one with  higher resolution

Answer (score 2):

turn the teapot clockwise, about 100 - 110 degree :)

the characters are:

```
棠吳
制省
```

“吳省棠” is a name, most likely the teapot maker; “制” means “make, fabricate”

anyway, “棠” is my best guess at this moment, take a clearer photo; please

Comment: Amazing. You are very good at the ancient Chinese 字體.

Comment: @r13, seal script & bronze script is not that difficult, with practises, you can also read with ease 

Comment: :) I often forgot and couldn't recognize my own writing that was made a few days ago :)!

Comment: @r13, maybe an outdated opinion: read and write daily (not type a han-chinese character by input method, nor speech recognition),  it helps 